# Using N, LIKE and % operator with stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-like

I have a c# application that call a stored procedure with one parameter. stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
 (@name  nvarchar(20))
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT     [pop].[Id]
              ,[pop].[name]
              ,[pop].[surname]
      FROM     [dbo].[pop]
      WHERE   ([pop].[name] LIKE N'%' +@name + '%')
      ORDER BY [pop].[Id]       

 END
```

but result set is incorrect, it doesn't return any table, (0 rows affected).

Comment: If you execute your SQL with the same @name value, does it return results? Add the "N" on the second %. You might want to add a SET NOCOUNT ON  at the beginning of the SP to prevent the "X rows affected" message to display.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Sql server 2012

Comment: Your procedure works well, might be searching data which doesn't exist

Comment: pls add same data